# "Notice: Undefined offset" when running the script with no values at both parameters

Tags: php, mysql

The following code is a part of my php script i build in order to display results from a mysql database. It is executed fine and I get the desirable results. However, when I run the script with both variables ("$search" and "$daterange") not set, I get a "Notice: Undefined offset" on the line I provide to you between " *** ". That Notice is not appeared in any other occasion.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Query: <input type="text" name="search" style="margin-bottom: 0px;" />

    <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on"></span>
        <input name="daterange" id="reportrange" type="text" value=""></input>
    </div>

    <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search Database"/>
</form>

<?php
    $conn  = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass) or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database, $conn);
    $search = false;
    $daterange = false;
    $from = false;
    $to = false;

    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $search = $_POST['search'];
    }

    // ***
    if(isset($_POST['daterange'])) {
        $daterange = $_POST['daterange'];
        list($from, $to) = preg_split('[ to ]', $daterange);
    }
    // ***

    if ($daterange==false) {
        $sql = "SELECT calendar.id, DATE(`start`) AS Date, CONCAT(TIME_FORMAT(`start`,'%H:%i'),'-',TIME_FORMAT(`end`,'%H:%i')) AS Time, title, description, 'open', fatherName, birthDate, occupation, address, postcode, cityArea, country, telNum, cellNum FROM patients INNER JOIN calendar ON title=CONCAT(lastName,' ',firstName) WHERE title like '%$search%' OR description like '%$search%' OR lastName like '%$search%' OR firstName like '%$search%' OR fatherName like '%$search%' OR birthDate like '%$search%' OR occupation like '%$search%' OR address like '%$search%' OR postcode like '%$search%' OR cityArea like '%$search%' OR country like '%$search%' OR telNum like '%$search%' OR cellNum like '%$search%' OR email like '%$search%' OR insuranceInstitution like '%$search%' OR insuranceId like '%$search%' ORDER BY Date DESC";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT calendar.id, DATE(`start`) AS 'Date', CONCAT(TIME_FORMAT(`start`,'%H:%i'),'-',TIME_FORMAT(`end`,'%H:%i')) AS Time, title, description, 'open', fatherName, birthDate, occupation, address, postcode, cityArea, country, telNum, cellNum FROM patients INNER JOIN calendar ON title=CONCAT(lastName,' ',firstName) WHERE (calendar.id like '%$search%' OR title like '%$search%' OR description like '%$search%' OR patientId like '%$search%' OR lastName like '%$search%' OR firstName like '%$search%' OR fatherName like '%$search%' OR birthDate like '%$search%' OR occupation like '%$search%' OR address like '%$search%' OR postcode like '%$search%' OR cityArea like '%$search%' OR country like '%$search%' OR telNum like '%$search%' OR cellNum like '%$search%' OR email like '%$search%' OR insuranceInstitution like '%$search%' OR insuranceId like '%$search%') AND (DATE(`start`) BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('$from', '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('$to', '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d'))";
    }

    $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());  
    .
    .
    //the rest of the code
    .
    .
?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: For error notice suppressing just put @ character in front of your code.  @$search

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't get your point...

Comment: Please put effort into formatting your code before posting it on StackOverflow. We want to help you, we really do, but if you WANT help, make it readable. Fixed it for you this time, but please do it in the future, even if you do not do it for your own convenience. On another note, please stop using the deprecated 'mysql' function in PHP, convert to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: The title answers the question... "no values at both parameters" causes "Notice: Undefined offset".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sending empty variables?

in that case use

```
 if( !empty($_POST['daterange']) ){

 }
```

empty returns true if the variable is an empty string, false, array(), NULL, “0?, 0, or an unset variable.

Read more: http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

```
if(isset($_POST['daterange']))
```

By:

```
if (array_key_exists('daterange',$_POST))
```